# Dividing before and after integration give different results

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics

I'm having a physics exercise, but the question is more of math.

Assuming I have the following constants: $m_1, m_2, \alpha, V_0$ and two variables: $v, t$. (v as velocity).

I reach the following equation, and I wish to extract $v(t)$ out of it:
$$ (m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t})dv=(\alpha\cdot{V_0})dt$$

Usually the lecturer does the following trick in order to get $v(t)$:
$$dv = \frac{\alpha\cdot{V_0}}{{m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t}}}dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{v}{dv} = \int_{0}^{t}{\frac{\alpha\cdot{V_0}}{{m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t}}}dt}$$

$$v = V_0 \cdot ln(\frac{m_1+m_2}{m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t}})$$

And that's the correct result.

But why when I decide not to divide before integration gives me a total different result?

$$ (m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t})dv=(\alpha\cdot{V_0})dt$$

$$\int_{0}^{v}(m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t})dv = \int_{0}^{t}(\alpha\cdot{V_0})dt$$

$$(m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t}) v = (\alpha\cdot{V_0})t$$

$$v = \frac{\alpha\cdot{V_0}}{m_1+m_2-\alpha\cdot{t}}$$

It's completely different.

How do this difference occur, and how can I know what the rules are?

Thank you.

Comment: Good point, I guess that's the problem. On the left hand side, I multiply it by v since it's an integration using dv (and I don't really have to subtract after integrating since it's from 0 to v)

Comment: You are basically solving a differential equation $\frac{dv}{dt}=f(v,t)$ by separation of variables. When you do that, you need to make sure that the terms depending on $v$ are 'next' to $dv$, and the terms depending on $t$ are 'next' to $dt$ before integrating. Here, you kept something dependent on $t$ next to $dv$ (so effectively you treated $t$ as a constant, which is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're solving a differential equation by separating the variables, but that technique is only valid if you actually *separate* the variables, and get all the $v$s on one side and all the $t$s on another side.

You're not doing that; instead you create the integral
$$ \int_0^v (m_1 + m_2 - \alpha t)\,dv $$
which contains both a $t$ and a $v$.

In the unknown solution to the differential equation you're trying to discover something about (say, a formula for it), $t$ and $v$ depend on each other in some particular way -- they're not independent of each other. But when you evaluate the above integral you're deciding to forget about that and treat $t$ as a constant, independent of $v$. Therefore you have no reason to expect that the outcome of the integral will match the integral to its right,  because you're pretending that the $t$ everywhere on the curve is equal to the *final* $t$ instead of varying with $v$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand. But how can I still separate the variables in a case I'm having a dv or dt free literal, like $(m_1+m_2−α⋅t)dv + v = ...$ ?

Comment: @Taru: Sometimes you just can't. Separation of the variables is not a universal technique for all ODEs, but a special case trick that works when the form of the equation happens to allow it.